# Sending speed 30% slower after upgrade to 4.7.30

Tags: civimail

We finished the migration on a fairly big database from 4.7.24 to 4.7.30, and now the sending speed is capped at 200kmails/h, where we were previously above 300k/h

any idea of what changed and cause that regression?

FYI: the trigger on modification date on activity is killing the update (we replicate the database), but I don't think it's related

Comment: What do you mean by 2.7.30 and 2.7.24? Are those civicrm version numbers?

Comment: oops, 4.7.30 and 4.7.24, fixed the typo, thanks